# Missing components in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, css-frameworks

Every component of Material UI is working fine but when I tried to use ImageList and ImageListItem for the first time I got this error

```
ERROR in ./client/src/user-imageboard.js 3:0-52
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/ImageList' in '/home/carlos/spiced/spiced-final-project/client/src'
 @ ./client/src/profile.js 13:0-47 58:26-40
 @ ./client/src/app.js 17:0-32 43:35-42
 @ ./client/src/start.js 10:0-24 25:32-35

ERROR in ./client/src/user-imageboard.js 4:0-60
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/ImageListItem' in '/home/carlos/spiced/spiced-final-project/client/src'
 @ ./client/src/profile.js 13:0-47 58:26-40
 @ ./client/src/app.js 17:0-32 43:35-42
 @ ./client/src/start.js 10:0-24 25:32-35
```

I checked on the node_modules folder and it's not there. I tried to delete the folder @material-ui/core and reinstalled again and still not there.

The component is nowhere to find it. Version of material-ui is `@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2"`

This is my component where are imported and nested.

```
import ImageList from '@material-ui/core/ImageList';
import ImageListItem from '@material-ui/core/ImageListItem';

const UserImageBoard = () => {
    return (
        <ImageList variant="masonry" cols={3} gap={8}>
            <ImageListItem>
                <img src="/default.jpg"> </img>
            </ImageListItem>
            <ImageListItem>
                <img src="/default.jpg"> </img>
            </ImageListItem>
            <ImageListItem>
                <img src="/default.jpg"> </img>
            </ImageListItem>
        </ImageList>
    );
};

export default UserImageBoard;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesnt appear to be an `ImageList` or `ImageListItem` component in [4.11.2](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/174b64f8a3adffb8df3c13285f4edc2437a8547a/packages/material-ui/src), which is currently the latest release.
You would need `@material-ui/core@next` which is currently `5.0.0-alpha.23` and does include those new components seen [here](https://next.material-ui.com/components/image-list/)

Comment: I agree and would like to add tath the situation is confusing:

As of today, the latest v4 release is 4.12.3, which does not include ImageList.

However, the v4 documentation mentions ImageList: https://v4.mui.com/components/image-list/

Also, ImageList exists in the v4.x-branch: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/v4.x/packages/material-ui/src/ImageList

Without digging in deeper, at least to me it is unclear if ImageList has ever been part of any v4 release or if it is only reserved for v5. Probably the latter. Time to migrate, I guess.